# Can we make sure that our app uses our version of SQLITE instead of the one which is provided by android.. by using Android NDK?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-ndk

our application is having problems working with default sqlite version provided in Android 2.1. 
So we want to use the customized sqlite version for our App. 
So my question is .. if we get the latest sqlite version from SQLITE.org and compile with android NDK, will we be able to invoke the our sqlite library when ever there are database operations happening in our application?
ex: if there is a call like "db.execSQL()" in Application code, How are we sure that it is gonna call the custom library?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to building your own sqlite shared object, you will need to replace one or more of the standard java sources from Android with your own (unless you actually just replace the platform's sqlite shared object). The platform framework loads /system/lib/libsqlite.so automatically.

I would suggest not naming your shared object libsqlite.so. I've seen Android's dlopen() being told to load two shared objects with different paths but the same name, only to have the first one opened twice.

Comment: hmm.. thanks for quick reply.. so in a way we have to replace all the links to the default sqlite. can be iterative and we cud end up replacing lot of files.. an i correct?

Comment: Yeah, depending on exactly how the framework code ties things together it could be very extensive. If you don't have a need for the Android database/cursor controls (and the very nice way it can tie things together such as through adapters) you could instead create your own Java access code to tie in your custom sqlite.